# including namespace in call to Javascript in Shiny module

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I use in my shiny apps custom shinyInput functions that facilitate building dynamic tables such that users can provide input from checkboxes, drop downs, text boxes, etc. to each row of a table. This functionality relies on calling Javascript in the UI and when generating output from DT::renderDataTable. This all works perfectly well when I use this tooling in the main app.R but I cannot get it to work when placed in a module. The problem almost certainly is that I need to include the namespace in the calls to the Javascript when in the module but I do not know where to do this. I have included code from a toy example illustrating the problem.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```r
# libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


# module UI ---------------------------------------------------------------

moduleUI <- function(id) {

    ns <- NS(id)

    fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput(ns("moduleOutput")),
        tags$script(HTML("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbind-DT', function(id) {
                                               Shiny.unbindAll($('#'+id).find('table').DataTable().table().node());
                                               })")),
        DT::dataTableOutput(ns("moduleWithRatingOutput"))
    ) # close the page

}


# module server -----------------------------------------------------------

mtcarsModule <- function(input, output, session) {


    # helper function to add interactive elements to rows of a table
    shinyInputOther <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
        inputs = character(len)
        for (i in seq_len(len)) {
            inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
        }
        inputs
    }

    # helper function to extract interactive elements from rows of a table
    shinyValue <- function(id, len) {
        unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
            value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
            if (is.null(value)) NA else value
        }))
    }


    # reactive data
    mtcarsReactive <- reactive({


        head(mtcars)

    }) # close reactive


    # reactive data output - allows adding a rating to each row/car
    output$moduleOutput <- DT::renderDataTable({

        mtcarsReactive() %>% 
            mutate(
                rating = shinyInputOther(FUN = selectInput,
                                         len = nrow(mtcarsReactive()),
                                         id = 'rating_',
                                         choices=c("high", "med", "low"),
                                         width = "60px")
            )
    },
    selection = 'none',
    escape = FALSE,
    server = FALSE,
    options = list(bFilter = 0,
                   bLengthChange = F,
                   bPaginate = F,
                   bSort = F,
                   preDrawCallback = JS('function() { 
                           Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'), 
                   drawCallback = JS('function() { 
                        Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ') 
    ),
    rownames = F) # close output


    # reactive data with added rating for each row/car
    mtcarsWithRating <- reactive({

        mtcarsReactive() %>%
            mutate(
                rating = shinyValue("rating_",
                                    nrow(mtcarsReactive())
                )
            )

    }) # close reactive


    # reactive data output - includes rating for each row/car
    output$moduleWithRatingOutput <- DT::renderDataTable({

        mtcarsWithRating()

    },
    selection = 'none',
    escape = FALSE,
    server = FALSE,
    options = list(bFilter = 0,
                   bLengthChange = F,
                   bPaginate = F,
                   bSort = F
    ),
    rownames = F) # close output

} # close module


# app UI ------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- navbarPage("mtcars",

                 # app tab
                 tabPanel("app",
                          fluidPage(
                              DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsOutput"),
                              tags$script(HTML("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbind-DT', function(id) {
                                               Shiny.unbindAll($('#'+id).find('table').DataTable().table().node());
                                               })")), 
                              DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsWithRatingOutput")
                          ) # close the page
                 ), # close tab


                 # module tab
                 tabPanel("module",
                          moduleUI("mtcarsModule")
                 ) # close tab

) # close navbarPage


# app server --------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {


    # helper function to add interactive elements to rows of a table
    shinyInputOther <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
        inputs = character(len)
        for (i in seq_len(len)) {
            inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
        }
        inputs
    }

    # helper function to extract interactive elements from rows of a table
    shinyValue <- function(id, len) {
        unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
            value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
            if (is.null(value)) NA else value
        }))
    }


    # reactive data
    mtcarsReactive <- reactive({

        head(mtcars)

    }) # close reactive


    # reactive data output - allows adding a rating to each row/car
    output$mtcarsOutput <- DT::renderDataTable({

        mtcarsReactive() %>% 
            mutate(
                rating = shinyInputOther(FUN = selectInput,
                                         len = nrow(mtcarsReactive()),
                                         id = 'rating_',
                                         choices=c("high", "med", "low"),
                                         width = "60px")
            )
    },
    selection = 'none',
    escape = FALSE,
    server = FALSE,
    options = list(bFilter = 0,
                   bLengthChange = F,
                   bPaginate = F,
                   bSort = F,
                   preDrawCallback = JS('function() { 
                           Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'), 
                   drawCallback = JS('function() { 
                        Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ') 
    ),
    rownames = F) # close output


    # reactive data with added rating for each row/car
    mtcarsWithRating <- reactive({

        mtcarsReactive() %>%
            mutate(
                rating = shinyValue("rating_",
                                    nrow(mtcarsReactive())
                )
            )

    }) # close reactive


    # reactive data output - includes rating for each row/car
    output$mtcarsWithRatingOutput  <- DT::renderDataTable({

        mtcarsWithRating()

    },
    selection = 'none',
    escape = FALSE,
    server = FALSE,
    options = list(bFilter = 0,
                   bLengthChange = F,
                   bPaginate = F,
                   bSort = F
    ),
    rownames = F) # close output


    # call module -------------------------------------------------------------

    callModule(module = mtcarsModule,
               id = "mtcarsModule")    


} # close server

# run the application -----------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT (2020-03-26): In case others run into this problem, the fix was to include `session$ns` in the `id` of the call to `shinyInputOther`. Using the included example, that looks like:

```r
rating = shinyInputOther(
  FUN = selectInput,
  len = nrow(mtcarsReactive()),
  id = paste0(session$ns('rating_')),
  choices=c("high", "med", "low"),
  width = "60px")
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the solution. Just solved the issue I'd be struggling with for 3 hours